# Fast Algorithm For Making Change With 6 Denominations: Interview Practice

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I came to a solution for this problem, but it takes O(n^2). Is it possible to do better?

Problem: Suppose we want to make change for D dollars. We have an array A with N elements. The denominations exist within the array as dollar values, but we do not know the exact denominations in advanced. However, we are given that 0 < A[j] < 125*N. The restrictions are, we only have 6 of each type of denomination and we must be able to determine if we can give change using **exactly** 6 total bills (we can repeat bills and assume bills come in any type, so we can have 4$ bills)..

Ex:
If A = [3,4,6,5,20,18,10,30] and D = 50. Then the algorithm returns true since  5+5+5+5+10+20.

My attempts:

I tried sorting and then dividing but then I get stuck because I am not sure how to eliminate possible choices since I do not know exactly what is in the array. Better yet, without explicitly going through in O(n^2) time, I am not sure how to for sure say that it is not possible. Is it possible to take advantage of the fact that I know I am restricted to exactly 6 bills?

Comment: It can be done in O(1) if you build a hash set lookup with the sums of all combinations. Generating the hash set is at most O(6*6) (6 bills and 6 type bills)

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like a typical recursion problem. Lets write a function that will check if we can make change for the `D` dollars. For that we will take the first bill (lets say it's $3), remove it from the the `D` and then recursively check if we can make change for the `D - 3` dollars.

We can make this solution much faster if we don't check the combinations that we have already checked. So if we already know that bills `3, 5, 10` don't fit our needs then we don't need to check the combination `5, 10, 3` either. For that we need firstly to sort the `A` array and then pass the number of last used bill (`last_bill_id`) to the `check` function. Inside the function we don't need to check any combinations with bills with number less than `last_bill_id`.

Full solution in python:

```py
A = [3, 4, 6, 5, 20, 18, 10, 30]
D = 50


def check(counters, current_sum, depth, last_bill_id):
    global A
    if depth > 6:  # max amount of bills is 6
        return False
    if depth == 6:  # we used 6 bill, did we get the correct sum?
        return current_sum == 0
    if current_sum <= 0:  # we gave too much change
        return False
    # current_sum > 0 and depth < 6
    for i in xrange(last_bill_id, len(A)):
        if counters[i] < 6:
            # we can use i-th bill another time
            counters[i] += 1
            if check(counters, current_sum - A[i], depth + 1, i):
                return True
            counters[i] -= 1
    return False


# init counters with zeros
counters = [0] * len(A)
# check if we can change for `D`
A = sorted(A)  # sort A before the function
print 'Can make change:', check(counters, D, 0, 0)
# print bills with counters
for i, c in enumerate(counters):
    if c > 0:
        print '$%d x %d' % (A[i], c)
```

Output:

> Can make change: True
>
> $3 x 4
>
> $18 x 1
>
> $20 x 1

---

### EDIT

Previous solution has complexity `O(n^6)`. But actually we can make it even faster with [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) (or, we put it in the other way, [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)). Lets sort the `A` array and repeat every number in it 6 times, so we'll get something like `A = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, ...]`. Now lets fill the 3D matrix `M[,,]`, where `M[bills_num, i, d]` is `true` iff we can make change for the `d` dollars with `bills_num` bills starting in `i`-th position of the `A` array. The result will be in the cell `M[6, 0, D]`. This matrix has size `6 x (6 * n) x D`, so we can fill it in `O(6 * (6 * n) * D) == O(n * D)` time (with the recursive approach similar to the solution before). Code in python:

```py
A = [3, 4, 6, 5, 20, 18, 10, 30]
D = 50

# sort A and repeat 6 times
A = sorted(A * 6)
# create matrix M, where:
# 0 == uncomputed, 1 == True, -1 == False
arr1d = lambda x: [0] * x
arr2d = lambda x, y: [arr1d(y) for i in xrange(x)]
arr3d = lambda x, y, z: [arr2d(y, z) for i in xrange(x)]
M = arr3d(6 + 1, len(A), D + 1)


def fill_m(bills_num, start_pos, d):
    global A, M
    if d == 0:  # can make change for 0 only with 0 bills
        return True if bills_num == 0 else False
    if d < 0 or bills_num <= 0 or start_pos >= len(A):
        return False
    if M[bills_num][start_pos][d] == 0:
        # need to compute cell value
        if fill_m(bills_num, start_pos + 1, d):
            M[bills_num][start_pos][d] = 1
        elif fill_m(bills_num - 1, start_pos + 1, d - A[start_pos]):
            M[bills_num][start_pos][d] = 1
        else:
            M[bills_num][start_pos][d] = -1
    return M[bills_num][start_pos][d] == 1


print 'Can make change for $', D, fill_m(6, 0, D)
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a runtime of O(n*D) yes? (Assuming we sort first & pass previous bill id).

Comment: Well, no. Recursive solution has `O(n^6)` complexity, but we can make the solution with `O(n * D)` complexity with help of dynamic programming, explained it in the answer.

Comment: Ah okay, I didnt quite read the first solution correctly. Thank you! I'll see if I can write the code with the second approach.